# How to prevent a4j:status from flickering when polled by a4j:poll

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am working on a project that uses a rich:tree element that, when expanded, should display a processing animation nearby using a4j:status. The problem that I am running into is that the tree is rerendered by multiple other elements. The one that I believe to be causing the most trouble is an a4j:push element that rerenders the tree every second. This rerendering is causing the status element to change states when it shouldn't, causing a flickering on screen.

My status element:

```
<a:outputPanel id="working_animation" style="display: block; height: 1px">
                    <!-- Working animation -->
                    <a:status  stopText=" " id="header_progress">
                        <a:facet name="start">
                            <a:outputPanel id="header_working" rendered="#{rich:element('tree_state.value').value}" style="padding-left: 16.5em;">
                                <span id="l-1"></span>
                                <span id="l-2"></span>
                                <span id="l-3"></span>
                                <span id="l-4"></span>
                                <span id="l-5"></span>
                                <span id="l-6"></span>
                            </a:outputPanel>
                        </a:facet>
                    </a:status>
</a:outputPanel>
```

Part of the tree element:

```
<rich:tree 
                            id="sectionTree"
                            switchType="ajax"
                            value="#{sectionAction.sectionNodes}"
                            var="node"
                            nodeFace="#{node.nodeType}"
                            rightClickSelection="true"
                            ajaxSubmitSelection="true"
                            iconCollapsed="/img/treenode/collapsed.png"
                            iconExpanded="/img/treenode/expanded.png"
                            componentState="#{sectionAction.treeState}">
                        <rich:changeExpandListener binding="#{sectionAction}" />
                        <rich:nodeSelectListener binding="#{sectionAction}" />
```

beyond that are node definitions

The push element:

```
<h:form>
        <a:push
            eventProducer="#{loggedUser.registerLoginListener}"
            interval="1000"
            reRender="sectionTree">
        </a:push>
        <a:push
            eventProducer="#{loggedUser.registerStudentListener}"
            interval="2000"
            reRender="sectionTree">
        </a:push>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options how to disable status:

1. Wrap `a:push` tags by `a:region`.
2. Specify `status="none"` attribute for `a:push`.

Refer to the livedemo for more details: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/status.jsf?c=status&tab=usage

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will try this and see if that will fix it.